# Access to main window from user control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have Login `User Control`, I want that when the user would click some button inside the user control I need it to make visible some `textBox`.

In main window I have:

```
<local:LoginUserCon />
<TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

I tried: (In Login User Control):

```
void Login_Btn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Application.Current.MainWindow.myTextBox.Visiblity = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

But it says:

> 'Window' does not contain a definition for 'myTextBox' and no accessible extension method 'myTextBox'...

Comment: You should probably read up about MVVM and databinding patterns, it will make your life easier in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Application.Current.MainWindow` returns a `Window`. You need to cast it to whatever your window type is, like for example `MainWindow`:

```
void Login_Btn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
    if (mainWindow != null)
        mainWindow.myTextBox.Visiblity = Visibility.Visible;
}
```